# SCRIPT1002: Syntax error - IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I am getting this error in IE9

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
bluebirdjobs.net, line 1587 character 5

While it is working fine in every other browsers

In IE-9 Footer does not show and display JS error.

Any help

My website is http://bluebirdjobs.net

I am not putting any JS function because i really don't have any idea which one is causing a problem.

Comment: This question is getting on now, but this may be of help: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Answer (score 2):

First, you should correct the HTML. You can use http://validator.w3.org to see errors.

There is something strange with a lot of the URLs, e.g. http://bluebirdjobs.net//?view=help

Also, http://bluebirdjobs.net//icons/arrow.png gives a 404 status.